# Problem with formula when creating calculated column when referenced column that has space in its name

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, calculated-column

Not sure what the problem is but when i use the following formula when creating a calculated column

```
=IF([Event Type]="","Black",IF([Event Type]="PFL","Red",IF([Event Type]="VCL","Gold",IF([Event Type]="HSL","Green",IF([Event Type]="FL3","DarkBlue",IF([Event Type]="FL1","DarkCyan",IF([Event Type]="RPL","DarkRed",IF([Event Type]="MM","Gray",IF([Event Type]="Vacation/Availability","Orange","")))))))))
```

I get an error "One or more column references are not allowed because the columns are defined as a data type that is not supported in formulas (Event Type is a choice)
If I use the same formula but with a one word named column like "Category" it creates it just fine.  Ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought the limit in calculated columns was 7 nested IF statements per branch.  You can [concatenate several nested ifs](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2010/04/12/maximum-number-of-if-statements-in-a-calculated-column/) to achieve your desired results.  Are you using [Christophe's color coded calendar tool](http://sp2010.pathtosharepoint.com/SharePoint-User-Toolkit/Pages/Color-Coding-Calendar-List.aspx) to generate that?  The calculated column looks identical, but I cannot make it generate the orange if, most likely it's bumping into the nested if limit.  Look over the first link and see if that helps you out.